# stop ajax function in midway when other element is clicked

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi have a page which has List data.

When I click on an element of the list, an Ajax function is called which populates some date in the right column.

Now wat's working:-

i click on element -> i see the loading.gif a few seconds -> data gets loaded.

When i click on other element midway, the first function completes and only then the second request is taken.

What I want:-

when i click and the ajax is loading, I click again in between, the previous function should stop, and my new request should be taken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stop AJAX requests (I'm guessing you don't want to actually stop the AJAX response handler function (which should take the least time in a usual AJAX scenario), but want to stop the request: [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/kill-ajax-requests-using-javascript-using-jquery):

Basically, store your request object somewhere (closure, global variable or wherever), and whenever you start a new request, check if an old one is still running, and if it is, call the `abort()` method on the old request!